What is the standard notation for bilinear, biquadratic, etc... spaces?
A typical notation for the polynomials of degree $k$ is $P_k$. The space $P_k$ is considered well-suited for interpolation on simplices, although that is hard to put into practice in full generality.
On the unit square, it is useful to consider the space $Q_k$ of polynomials of "max degree $k$". For example, $Q_1$ is spanned by $\{1,x,y,xy\}$. These functions are said to be "bilinear", i.e. a linear polynomial in each variable $x,y$ separately (not to be confused with "bilinear form" in linear algebra.) Functions in $Q_2$ are quadratic in each $x,y$ separately, etc...
$Q_k$ is the "right space" for interpolation on the square. Interpolation on the square in $Q_k$ is much simpler than on the simplex in $P_k$.
What's the standard notation for $Q_k$?

I don't think there is one standard notation but $F[x,y]^{\leq k}$, where $F$ is the base field, is one someone might be able to figure out before seeing the definition.

The term "standard notation" is a relative concept. In the finite element world, the standard notation is indeed $Q_k$, and the polynomials therein are referred to as "tensor product polynomials" or as being "of partial degree $k$", or simply bilinear, biquadratic, bicubic etc (in two dimensions), trilinear etc. (in three dimensions).
The statement that the $P_k$ spaces are hard to put in practice in full generality is, by the way, not entirely true. This very much depends on the way your code is designed.

Thanks for this. About finite elements on triangles, I was referring to this; it's not as simple as quadrilaterals. Also, lumped mass matrices have the tendency to be indefinite, which is posing problems for me.
